# R: What are the best functions to deal with concatenating and averaging values in a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation, average

I have a data.frame from this code:

```
   my_df = data.frame("read_time" = c("2010-02-15", "2010-02-15", 
                                      "2010-02-16", "2010-02-16", 
                                       "2010-02-16", "2010-02-17"), 
                      "OD" = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5) )
```

which produces this:

```
> my_df
   read_time  OD
1 2010-02-15 0.1
2 2010-02-15 0.2
3 2010-02-16 0.1
4 2010-02-16 0.2
5 2010-02-16 0.4
6 2010-02-17 0.5
```

I want to average the OD column over each distinct read_time (notice some are replicated others are not) and I also would like to calculate the standard deviation, producing a table like this:

```
> my_df
   read_time  OD        stdev
1 2010-02-15 0.15       0.05
5 2010-02-16 0.3         0.1
6 2010-02-17 0.5         0
```

Which are the best functions to deal with concatenating such values in a data.frame?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [**plyr**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=plyr) package is popular for this, but the base functions `by()` and `aggregate()` will also help.

```
> ddply(my_df, "read_time", function(X) data.frame(OD=mean(X$OD),stdev=sd(X$OD)))
   read_time      OD   stdev
1 2010-02-15 0.15000 0.07071
2 2010-02-16 0.23333 0.15275
3 2010-02-17 0.50000      NA
```

You can add the missing bit to return 0 instead of NA for the last std.dev.

Also, you don't need the quotes (on the variables) you had in the data.frame construction.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, that works well with the plyr package, but could you tell me how to add another column to the data, I have another column named day in my real dataset.  I tried this: ddply(individual_well_series_od, "read_time", function(X) data.frame(od=mean(X$od),stdev=sd(X$od), day=X$day))  but it returns a all of the read_times again.  I realize that I'm not applying a function to day, but I read the help but can't see where to put it.

Comment: And I tried the original code without the "" around the dates, but the dates did not read correctly, so I kept them in, I could have tried to convert them to date objects I presume, but I kept it as this simple example.

Comment: Not the dates, the variables, ie use data.frame(a=1:3) and not data.frame("a"=1:3)

As for adding a variable, you can't -- the ddply call *reduces* several rowns to a single-row summary.  If you add an original data column then you get repeats.  You got to think this through.

Comment: Or with the built in `summarize` helper function: `ddply(my_df, "read_time", summarise, OD = mean(OD), stdev = sd(OD))`

Comment: summarize (with z) or summarise (with s) or both?  ;-)  R is quite charming in its support of British and American spelling...

Comment: thanks, it works nicely with summarize too.  I also fixed the new variables by including e.g.  days = unique(days)

Comment: But unique(days) could return more than one. You could try head(days,1) or even head(unique(days), 1).

Answer (score 3):

You can try the package data.table. If you know MySQL it should be very easy for you to get all the functions, otherwise the basics are good enough too ;-)

```
my_dfdt<-data.table(my_df)
mean<-my_dfdt[,mean(OD), by="read_time"]
sd<-  ..
```

you can also join both in one line or to cbind at the end, your call of style

Another advantage: it is extremely fast, if you have large samples. Very fast...see documentation why.

Answer (score 1):

This illustrates how you could use `aggregate` to get the mean and standard deviation by your `read_time`.

```
>aggregate(my_df$OD, by=list(my_df$read_time), function(x) mean(x))

     Group.1         x
1 2010-02-15 0.1500000
2 2010-02-16 0.2333333
3 2010-02-17 0.5000000


>aggregate(my_df$OD, by=list(my_df$read_time), function(x) sd(x))
     Group.1          x
1 2010-02-15 0.07071068
2 2010-02-16 0.15275252
3 2010-02-17         NA
```

Comment: If you just want an existing function called, you don't have to define your own anonymous function. You can pass the existing function:

aggregate(my_df$OD,by=list(my_df$read_time),mean)