# How can I collapse a dataframe by some variables, taking mean across others

Tags: r, ggplot2, pivot-table

I need to summarize a data frame by some variables, ignoring the others. This is sometimes referred to as collapsing. E.g. if I have a dataframe like this:

```
Widget Type Energy  
egg 1 20  
egg 2 30  
jap 3 50  
jap 1 60
```

Then collapsing by Widget, with Energy the dependent variable,   Energy~Widget, would yield

```
Widget Energy  
egg  25  
jap  55
```

In Excel the closest functionality might be "Pivot tables" and I've worked out how to do it in python ( http://alexholcombe.wordpress.com/2009/01/26/summarizing-data-by-combinations-of-variables-with-python/), and here's an example with R using doBy library to do something very related ( http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg02643.html), but is there an easy way to do the above?  And even better is there anything built into the ggplot2 library to create plots that collapse across some variables?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `aggregate` to summarize across a factor:

```
> df<-read.table(textConnection('
+ egg 1 20
+ egg 2 30
+ jap 3 50
+ jap 1 60'))
> aggregate(df$V3,list(df$V1),mean)
  Group.1  x
1     egg 25
2     jap 55
```

For more flexibility look at the `tapply` function and the `plyr` package.

In `ggplot2` use `stat_summary` to summarize

```
qplot(V1,V3,data=df,stat="summary",fun.y=mean,geom='bar',width=0.4)
```

Comment: `by` also comes in handy from time to time.

Comment: for an example using `ddply` from the `plyr` package take a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473659/r-what-are-the-best-functions-to-deal-with-concatenating-and-averaging-values-in

Comment: i would check out plyr for a general purpose SAC combine framework (what pivot tables are), it's an excellent resource

Comment: Thanks! it's taken me awhile to get my head around ggplot2 stat. Here's what I wanted exactly, I think: ggplot(data=df,aes(x=Widget,y=Energy))+  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,ymin=10,ymax=60)

Comment: Do you really want the long line? Otherwise `stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom='point')` produces just the points.

Answer (score 5):

For those familiar with SQL, another way to manipulate dataframes can be the sqldf command in the sqldf package.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT Widget, avg(Energy) FROM yourDataFrame GROUP BY Widget")
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jyotirmoy mentioned that this can be done with the `plyr` library. Here is what that would look like:

```
DF <- read.table(text=
"Widget Type Energy  
egg 1 20  
egg 2 30  
jap 3 50  
jap 1 60", header=TRUE)

library("plyr")
ddply(DF, .(Widget), summarise, Energy=mean(Energy))
```

which gives

```
> ddply(DF, .(Widget), summarise, Energy=mean(Energy))
  Widget Energy
1    egg     25
2    jap     55
```