# How to generate summary information and error bars in R

Tags: r

I have a set of data:

```
COL1   COL2
1      3.45
2      8.48
1      2.53
2      9.42
2      2.56
etc.
```

COL1 specifies a category, whereas COL2 is data. I'd like to, for each distinct value in COL1 generate mean, stddev, min & max values. So in the end have something like (not real numbers):

```
COL1VAL    MEAN     STDDEV
1          4.59     1.24
2          4.75     1.20
```

I'd also then like to generate a bar chart with error bars, with X axis being the COL1VAL and bar height being the mean.

Can one do this in R, and if so, how?

Comment: Have you done any searching? I get literally hundreds of SO hits on `[r] error bars`

Comment: Yeah, I did quite a bit of searching (despite what people may think, it is easier to search and find an answer than type all this stuff out into a question). The error bars part isn't the particularly difficult part, its the summarizing based on category and getting out the category statistics. I regret asking about the error bars now, as its clouds the important question about the summaries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R: What are the best functions to deal with concatenating and averaging values in a data.frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473659/r-what-are-the-best-functions-to-deal-with-concatenating-and-averaging-values-i). But as @BondedDust writes, there are heaps of similar posts on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could do those things using packages `dplyr` and `ggplot2`, assuming your data frame is called `df`.

```
library(dplyr)

dfsummary <- df %>%
  group_by(COL1) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean, sd, min, max))

dfsummary
#Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
#
#  COL1 mean        sd  min  max
#1    1 2.99 0.6505382 2.53 3.45
#2    2 6.82 3.7190859 2.56 9.42

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dfsummary, aes(x = factor(COL1), y = mean)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "lightblue") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd))
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to stay in base R, you could use tapply and arrows:

```
head(chickwts, 15) # chicken growth depending on food#

means <- tapply(X=chickwts$weight, INDEX=chickwts$feed, FUN=mean)
sds   <- tapply(X=chickwts$weight, INDEX=chickwts$feed, FUN=sd  )
or <- order(means)

bp <- barplot(means[or], ylim=c(0, 390), las=2)
arrows(x0=bp, y0=(means+sds)[or], y1=(means-sds)[or], 
       code=3, angle=90, length=0.1)
```

Regards,
Berry